# Configuring "additionalScrapeConfigs" using `helm --set` on the command line

Tags: prometheus, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I'm trying to deploy an application which includes [Bitnami's Prometheus](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/kube-prometheus/) operator using Helm. I would like to configure the Prometheus operator's [`additionalScrapeConfig`](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/kube-prometheus/#additional-scrape-configurations) section in order to add scraping of application specific metrics.

This configuration could be set in my Helm chart's `values.yaml` file, but in order to make this work for different environments (test/staging/production) I would like to supply this configuration via Helm's `--set` command line parameter. This is what I'm currently have (executed by a Github action):

```bash
helm upgrade my-application ./.helm \
  --install
  --wait
  --atomic
  --set some_variable=1234
  # Below is the interesting part:
  --set kube-prometheus.prometheus.additionalScrapeConfigs.enabled=true
  --set kube-prometheus.prometheus.additionalScrapeConfigs.type=internal
  --set kube-prometheus.prometheus.additionalScrapeConfigs.internal.jobList="- job_name: 'my-application-metric' \
  static_configs: \
  - targets: ['my-application-metrics-service:5002'] \
    labels: \
      app: my-application" \
  --set another_variable=54321
```

The above Helm command successfully deploys the Helm chart but the Prometheus operator log contains the following error messages:

```
sync \"my-application-namespace/my-application-kube-prome-prometheus\" failed: creating config failed: generating config failed: generate additional scrape configs: unmarshalling additional scrape configs failed: yaml: did not find expected key
```

So, I guess that the resulting YAML configuration is invalid somehow. And I have two questions:

First, if anyone can spot any obvious errors (white spaces in the scrape config YAML string?), please let me know :-).

Second, does anyon know where the configuration YAML is stored on the running pods? If I could inspect it I suspect it would be much easier to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

Through some extensive trial and error I figured out the problem of my `helm` command.

I had included trailing `\` in each row in my jobList string. Since the jobList string was a string literal (enclosed in `"`) this was not necessary/wrong.

The correct command should be:

```bash
helm upgrade my-application ./.helm \
  --install
  --wait
  --atomic
  --set some_variable=1234
  --set kube-prometheus.prometheus.additionalScrapeConfigs.enabled=true
  --set kube-prometheus.prometheus.additionalScrapeConfigs.type=internal
  --set kube-prometheus.prometheus.additionalScrapeConfigs.internal.jobList="- job_name: 'my-application-metric'
  static_configs:
  - targets: ['my-application-metrics-service:5002']
    labels:
      app: my-application" \
  --set another_variable=54321
```